# Is it possible to automate Bloomberg Terminal's tasks?

Tags: python, api, automation, screen-scraping, bloomberg

I have access to a bloomberg terminal and python on the same computer. I tried to look on internet and on this forum for some useful tips/introduction to automate bloomberg tasks, although I didn't find anything. How can the terminal be automated? Is it possible to do something similar to webscraping with an external application? Or the only way is to use Sendkeys method? (In my case I want to automate ISIN typing, print screen (for which I found a code in this forum using API calls) and data analysis (so scrape the data showed). I'm aware of bloomberg add-in for excel but it's quite limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automating the terminal can be done using the TerminalConnect Api.

It's not possible to 'scrape' data from the terminal, but you can access data using the Desktop Api (DAPI).

Comment: Thank you. I'm quite new into coding (few months) but i didn't find any material on the web to understand API, i know what it is but not how to use it. When you want to automate a program through API (not windows program) how you start doing it? Do you have any useful material to understand it? Even though i will access to DAPI i don't know where to start.

Comment: WAPI<GO> will take you to where you can download DAPI SDK and Developer Guides from. The SDK contains full code examples in 4 different programming languages: C++, C#, Java and Python, and the binaries for Windows, Linux and SOLARIS. Start with RefdataExample, review the code, then run it to send a simple ReferenceDataRequest with one or more securities and fields.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use the API.

Bloomberg makes it easy to do this in Excel. You need to install Bloomberg API plugin.

If you need to do this ‘programmatically’, there are API written in different languages. Use WAPI in your terminal to find out.